# How to access variables in a Vue component from the JS Console?

Tags: vue.js

I have a template like this:

```
<template>
  <div>{{hello}}</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    hello: "Hello World!",
    secret: "The answer is 42"
  }
}
</script>
```

How can I get, and manipulate the value of `secret` from the Chrome debugging console?

I have installed the Vue extension which allows me to look at my component and see the variables. What I would like to do is to get these variables and manipulate them.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you are running vue in debug/test mode, have you tried accessing accessing the values in the console, assigning a new value, etc

Comment: I haven't tried, I don't know how to get the values. Is this something like `window.vue.mycomponent.data.foo`?

Comment: Directly in the console assign a value to the vue variable or prop defined in the template

Comment: I don't understand your point. In my console I have this prompt: `>`. What should I write in the case I want to change the value of `secret`?

Comment: foo = "newvalue" ie. if foo is a vue prop already defined

Comment: `secret` is not a global variable it belongs to a `Vue` component

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is a similar discussion on the Vue.js forum.  Specifically, [SevenLines post on Mar 25 2018](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-access-vue-from-chrome-console/3606/5) reads:

> Update from 2018. If you use vue-devtools, you can access Vue from
>   console by selecting desired component, and then accessing it through
>   $vm variable. Check the image with example:
>
> [image: Example image]

Comment: Ok... the answer is then `$vm0.secret` then.

Answer (score 34):

I use this

```js
// if result is single element
document.getElementById('app').__vue__

// if result is multiple elements
document.getElementsByClassName('some-class')[0].__vue__
```

assuming your using id #app for your entry

can also do it in other elements as long as identified as Vue Component
[element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgM16.png)

and get element by tag/id/class

Comment: I am not able to get this in production mode though... What could be the reason and what could the solution be?

Comment: With Vue3 it seems to be `__vue_app__`, not `__vue__`.
`document.getElementById('app').__vue_app__`

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I put in the Console, and it immediately modifies the data shown on the page:

```
myapp = app.__vue__.$children[0]
myapp.hello = 'Bonjour'
myapp.hello = 'Buenos dias'
```

Mysteriously, if you skip assigning the object to a variable, it doesn't work as intended:

```
app.__vue__.$children[0].hello = 'Bonjour'       // first time it works
app.__vue__.$children[0].hello = 'Buenos dias'   // second time it doesn't work
```

Comment: any idea why the autocomplete doesn;t work when not assigned to a variable. Weird!!

Comment: This appears to leverage some sort of shorthand in devtools; using `app` actually seems to be doing `document.getElementById('app')` under the hood, and returns an HTML element with an `id` attribute matching the typed name– in this case, the element you've rooted your Vue instance in.

Answer (score 2):

In 2023, Vue 3, to access:

- data: $vm.data.yourProperty
- computed: $vm.ctx.yourProperty
- props: $vm.props.yourProperty

It works with vm0 too, since they are aliases for the last component click on DevTools

[image: console]

Comment: `$vm0` and `$vm` are `undefined` for me. Can you elaborate on "they are aliases for the last component click on DevTools"?

Answer (score 0):

At least with the "vue.global.js" VueJS 3.3.11 build, you can access the Vue instance by doing:

```
const el = document.getElementById('#myvue');
// replace "#myvue" with the ID of the element you mounted your component using the "mount" method
const secret = el.__vue_app__._instance.proxy.secret;
// if you want to access the "secret" data
```

`el.__vue_app__._instance.proxy` is eq to `el.__vue__` in VueJS 2.x

Answer (score 0):

in a vue3 app, the following will get you not only the component, but any variables declared in `<script setup>` (if your component is an SFC):

```js
// get the component in the DOM
const domComponent = document.getElementById("my-component");
// get the vue component instance
const vueComponent = domComponent.__vnode.component;
// get the setup variables
const state = vueComponent.setupState;
```