# How to access Vue data in Vue-CLI in browser console

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-cli

I saw many answers telling to use vue-devtools to access the Vue Object but is there a way to do it in the browser console? Like in the tutorial, we enter

`> app.data.sock`

in console to get the data

Let's say:

**main.js**

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

**App.vue**

```html
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <HelloWorld />
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
</script>
```

**HelloWorld.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="title in titles" :key="title.id">{{ title.name }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data() {
    return {
      titles: [{
        id: 0,
        name: "a"
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "b"
      }]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

How do I access the data of 'titles' in HelloWorld.vue? In other word, how to get `this.data.titles[0].name` in the HelloWorld.vue in the browser console? Thank you

Comment: please paste complete component code

Comment: maybe here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51848439/how-to-access-variables-in-a-vue-component-from-the-js-console are talking about you :)

Comment: @AliasgherNooruddin edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the value of data function in created our mounted hooks of Vue lifecycle or can create a function in methods. I am calling your data in created hook

---

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data() {
    return {
      titles: [{
        id: 0,
        name: "a"

      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "b"
      }]
    }
  },
 created(){
     console.log(this.data.tiles)
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: to learn more about mounted and created  [see this](https://lavalite.org/blog/created-and-mountedin-vuejs)

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to it on the browser itself? For example entering `this.data.titles[0].name` in the browser console and it will reply `a`

Comment: No its not possible install vue dev tools there you can check vue objects whenever you want